# Always on top div within area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

I created a div that is always on top

```
.visibleDiv, #topLeft
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #ffdab9;
    text-align: center;
}

#topLeft
{
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

And I display it like so

```
<div id="topLeft">
    Top Left
</div>
```

But I also have a div called container. And i would like topLeft to stay at the top left within that container instead of the top left of the screen. I am quite new to css and have been scratching my head for a while on how to achieve such an effect.

So to explain more clearly I would like to try to achieve this effect

```
______________
|Other things|
|____________|
________________________________
| TOP LEFT MESSAGE|            |
|_________________|            |
|                              |
|                              |
|         CONTAINER DIV        |
|                              |
|                              |
```

And when you scroll down I want the topleft to be at top left of screen within container tab like so

```
|__________________            |
| TOP LEFT MESSAGE|            |
|_________________|            |
|                              |
|                              |
|         CONTAINER DIV        |
|                              |
|                              |
|______________________________|
```

If anyone could point me in right direction or show me how to achieve that with an explanation I would be really grateful. Thank you to anyone in advance for helping or just reading this post.

Comment: You should probably add a `javascript` tag because this certainly cannot be done in just CSS.

Comment: Okay, you want the element at the top left of its container initially, but then when you start scrolling, you want to fix it to the top left of the screen?

Comment: @Purmou I want it to stay fixed at top left within container. I pretty much want something like this http://papermashup.com/ only within a certain div tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add position:relative to your container element.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VzBbr/)

**Update**

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is very useful here. You can use it to easily calculate when the "container" hits this top of the view port then re-assign a class to your "topLeft" element to fix it.

HTML

```
<div class="head">
Some Stuff
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="topLeft">Top Left Stuff</div>
    Container Stuff
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{

    background-color:#FAA;
    height:1000px;
}

#topLeft
{
    width: 150px;
    border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #ffdab9;
    text-align: center;
}

.fixit
{
    position:fixed;

    top: 0px;
}
```

Javascript

```
<!-- Include jQuery Library -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<!-- Wire Up Our Magic -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if(($(".container").position().top - $(window).scrollTop()) <= 0)
       {
           $("#topLeft").addClass("fixit");
       }
       else
       {
           $("#topLeft").removeClass("fixit");
       }

    });
});

</script>
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VzBbr/4/)

Comment: That is the exact same effect I keep on getting too. See the problem is that I want it that when you scroll the page down and top part of the container disappears then the "Top Left Stuff" goes to the top of the screen

Comment: In which case you will need some javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. And I had no idea that I could do it using javascript. Thanks a lot for a great lesson!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/TSfLu/

The Top left Message would always be at that position and cover anything below it. So you might want to position the content on your page accordingly.